# List Tag Value - EC2 Boto3

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

My understanding is I'm supposed to use `resource` when using Boto3 :)

The following returns all the key/value pairs; how would I get a specific key value? I'm looking print out the name given to the instance.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    print (instance.tags)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use either the boto3 resource or client interfaces. The resource interface is a higher level which is easier (simpler) to work with. The client interface is lower layer and you have more fine grained control. Start off with using resource and later switch to client as you better understand Python / boto3 / AWS SDKs.

Here is an example that will print the Value value.

The key parts to understand is that `instance.tags` is an array of Python dict (dictionary). You need to loop thru this array to get to each "`Value`". When accessing a dict you use this syntax `['name_of_item']`.

AWS stores tags as `Key` and `Value`. These are the names to use when processing the dict.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

for instance in ec2.instances.all():
        print (instance.tags)
        for tag in instance.tags:
                print(tag['Value'])
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Still stuck; not understanding something or approaching this wrong. I just want `{'Key': 'Name', 'Value: '*'}` or the name of all the EC2 instances.

Comment: Did you ruin my code? Did it output the your tags? I would suggest spending some time learning what the code does and how Python works.

Comment: Your code was very helpful. Someone showed me the way they did it. They created a list of instance.id(s) then looped through the instance ids. Similar to your loop through tags then they, `if tags['Key'] == 'Name':`

Comment: The title of your question is "List Tag Value - EC2 Boto3".